# Complete string values in a column guided by numeric values in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
ID    URINE_TEST   UNIT  VALUE 
1         'alb'    mg    1500 
2         'alb'    mg    1200 
3         'alb'    mg    1600 
4         'alb'    g     1.2 
5         'alb'    g     1.8 
7         'alb'    NaN   1300 <- should become mg
8         'crt'    l     2.3 
9         'crt'    l     3.3
10        'crt'    l     4.1 
11        'crt'    ml    2500 
12        'crt'    ml    3400 
13        'crt'    ml    2100 
14        'crt'    NaN   3.0  <-should become l
15        'crt'    NaN   99  <-should stay as NaN (not inside any range)
```

I would like to complete where the UNIT column is NaN.

Here I explain. Let's take urine test "alb" (albumine) as example. As you can see, there is one test result (ID:7) that doesn't specify a unit. However, just by looking the VALUE ranges of the other units (mg and g), it's evident that this NaN should be mg. Because its value 1300 is similar in value to the mg's values (See table). I.e. it falls within the value range of "mg" values [1200-1600].

Same case for urine test "crt" (creatinine) (ID:14), where unit NaN shoud be l (liter), just by looking at the value range for unit l: [2.3 - 4.1]. Lastly, ID:15, should remain as NaN (doesn't fall within any value range.)

Having said that, I would like to make a program that assigns the corresponding unit for all the urine tests in a big dataset, IF the value falls within the same range as other unit. Otherwise, leave unit as NaN.

I have started by doing `df.groupby([urine_test, unit]).value.transform('min')` and 'max':

```
ID    URINE_TEST   UNIT  VALUE  MIN     MAX
1         'alb'    mg    1500   1200    1600
2         'alb'    mg    1200   1200    1600
3         'alb'    mg    1600   1200    1600
4         'alb'    g     1.2    1.2     1.8
5         'alb'    g     1.8    1.2     1.8
7         'alb'    NaN   1300 
8         'crt'    l     2.3    2.3     4.1
9         'crt'    l     3.3    2.3     4.1
10        'crt'    l     4.1    2.3     4.1
11        'crt'    ml    2500   2100    3400
12        'crt'    ml    3400   2100    3400
13        'crt'    ml    2100   2100    3400 
14        'crt'    NaN   3.0  
15        'crt'    NaN   99
```

But I can't really figure out a way to do this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution if `ID` values are unique:

```
#filter NaNs rows by UNIT
df1 = df[df['UNIT'].isna()]
print (df1)
    ID URINE_TEST UNIT   VALUE
5    7      'alb'  NaN  1300.0
12  14      'crt'  NaN     3.0
13  15      'crt'  NaN    99.0
```

---

```
#aggregate min and max values
df2 = df.groupby(['URINE_TEST', 'UNIT']).VALUE.agg(['min','max']).reset_index()
print (df2)
  URINE_TEST UNIT     min     max
0      'alb'    g     1.2     1.8
1      'alb'   mg  1200.0  1600.0
2      'crt'    l     2.3     4.1
3      'crt'   ml  2100.0  3400.0
```

---

```
#join together and filter between values, create Series of UNIT values
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on='URINE_TEST', suffixes=('_',''))
s = df3[df3['VALUE'].between(df3['min'], df3['max'])].set_index(['ID'])['UNIT']
print (s)
ID
7     mg
14     l
Name: UNIT, dtype: object
```

---

```
#replace NaNs with s Series
df['UNIT'] = df['ID'].map(s).fillna(df['UNIT'])
```

Or:

```
m = df['UNIT'].isna()
df.loc[m, 'UNIT'] = df.loc[m, 'ID'].map(s)

print (df)
    ID URINE_TEST UNIT   VALUE
0    1      'alb'   mg  1500.0
1    2      'alb'   mg  1200.0
2    3      'alb'   mg  1600.0
3    4      'alb'    g     1.2
4    5      'alb'    g     1.8
5    7      'alb'   mg  1300.0
6    8      'crt'    l     2.3
7    9      'crt'    l     3.3
8   10      'crt'    l     4.1
9   11      'crt'   ml  2500.0
10  12      'crt'   ml  3400.0
11  13      'crt'   ml  2100.0
12  14      'crt'    l     3.0
13  15      'crt'  NaN    99.0
```

Solution with `merge` and left join is most general:

```
df1 = df[df['UNIT'].isna()]
df2 = df.groupby(['URINE_TEST', 'UNIT']).VALUE.agg(['min','max']).reset_index()

df3 = df1.merge(df2, on='URINE_TEST', suffixes=('_',''))
df3 = df3.loc[df3['VALUE'].between(df3['min'], df3['max']), ['URINE_TEST','VALUE', 'UNIT']]
df3 = df1.merge(df3, on=['URINE_TEST','VALUE'], suffixes=('_',''), how='left')
print (df3)
   ID URINE_TEST UNIT_   VALUE UNIT
0   7      'alb'   NaN  1300.0   mg
1  14      'crt'   NaN     3.0    l
2  15      'crt'   NaN    99.0  NaN

df = (pd.concat([df.dropna(subset=['UNIT']), df3[df.columns]])
        .sort_values('URINE_TEST')
        .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df)
    ID URINE_TEST UNIT   VALUE
0    1      'alb'   mg  1500.0
1    2      'alb'   mg  1200.0
2    3      'alb'   mg  1600.0
3    4      'alb'    g     1.2
4    5      'alb'    g     1.8
5    7      'alb'   mg  1300.0
6    8      'crt'    l     2.3
7    9      'crt'    l     3.3
8   10      'crt'    l     4.1
9   11      'crt'   ml  2500.0
10  12      'crt'   ml  3400.0
11  13      'crt'   ml  2100.0
12  14      'crt'    l     3.0
13  15      'crt'  NaN    99.0
```

Alternative with match by unique undex in `df1`:

```
df1 = df[df['UNIT'].isna()]
df2 = df.groupby(['URINE_TEST', 'UNIT']).VALUE.agg(['min','max']).reset_index()

#add index to columns by reset_index()
df3 = df1.reset_index().merge(df2, on='URINE_TEST', suffixes=('_',''))
s = df3[df3['VALUE'].between(df3['min'], df3['max'])].set_index(['index'])['UNIT']
print (s)
index
5     mg
12     l
Name: UNIT, dtype: object

df['UNIT'] = df['UNIT'].fillna(s)
print (df)
    ID URINE_TEST UNIT   VALUE
0    1      'alb'   mg  1500.0
1    2      'alb'   mg  1200.0
2    3      'alb'   mg  1600.0
3    4      'alb'    g     1.2
4    5      'alb'    g     1.8
5    7      'alb'   mg  1300.0
6    8      'crt'    l     2.3
7    9      'crt'    l     3.3
8   10      'crt'    l     4.1
9   11      'crt'   ml  2500.0
10  12      'crt'   ml  3400.0
11  13      'crt'   ml  2100.0
12  14      'crt'    l     3.0
13  15      'crt'  NaN    99.0
```

Comment: The IDs aren't unique. It'd be great if you can alter your solution to be ID agnostic. Thanks

Comment: @Kaisar - Answer was edited with 2 new solutions ID agnostic.

Answer (score 1):

As in your logic, you only `fillna` on values within range of min-max and keep other `NaN` intact. I think you may achieve it with `sort_values`, `ffill` and `loc` assigment using custom masks to set `NaN` back to those are outside of min-max range

```
df1 = df.sort_values(['VALUE', 'UNIT'])
m1 = df1.UNIT.shift() != df1.UNIT.shift(-1)
m2 = df1.UNIT.isna()
m3 = df1.VALUE != df1.VALUE.shift()
df1['UNIT'] = df1.UNIT.ffill()
df1.loc[m1 & m2 & m3, 'UNIT'] = np.nan
df = df1.reindex(df.index)

Out[130]:
    ID URINE_TEST UNIT   VALUE
0    1      'alb'   mg  1500.0
1    2      'alb'   mg  1200.0
2    3      'alb'   mg  1600.0
3    4      'alb'    g     1.2
4    5      'alb'    g     1.8
5    7      'alb'   mg  1300.0
6    8      'crt'    l     2.3
7    9      'crt'    l     3.3
8   10      'crt'    l     4.1
9   11      'crt'   ml  2500.0
10  12      'crt'   ml  3400.0
11  13      'crt'   ml  2100.0
12  14      'crt'    l     3.0
13  15      'crt'  NaN    99.0
```

Comment: What ``` m1 = df1.UNIT.shift() != df1.UNIT.shift(-1)``` do?

Comment: Your solution is definitely the most elegant but quite mysterious to me.

Comment: @Kaisar: It checks previous row against next row. If they are different and current row is ‘NaN’, check further on ‘df1.VALUE‘

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understood your conditions correctly and the datatype of your values are float:

```
# List for new unit values.

NEW_UNIT = []

# For loop that checks each row in the dataframe for its respective values.

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['URINE_TEST'] == 'alb':
        if (row['VALUE'] >= 1200) and (row['VALUE'] <= 1600):
            NEW_UNIT.append('mg')
        elif (row['VALUE'] >= 1.2) and (row['VALUE'] <= 1.6):
            NEW_UNIT.append('g')
        else:
            NEW_UNIT.append(float('NaN'))
    elif row['URINE_TEST'] == 'crt':
        if (row['VALUE'] >= 2300) and (row['VALUE'] <= 4100):
            NEW_UNIT.append('ml')
        elif (row['VALUE'] >= 2.3) and (row['VALUE'] <= 4.1):
            NEW_UNIT.append('l')
        else:
            NEW_UNIT.append(float('NaN'))

# Replace unit column with the updated unit values

df['UNIT'] = NEW_UNIT
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. However, usually, answer snippets in SO are expected to work programatically. E.g. those min/max should be calculated automatically. Also the answer should work for any number of urine tests in URINE_TESTS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DataFrame.apply()` function to clean the data and get desired results. You can read more about `df.apply()` in the docs.

A rough solution will look like this, assuming the data is called `urine_data`:

```
#create a dictionary of all the tests and their different options and min, max values
test_dic = {'alb': [('mg', 1200, 1800), ('g', 1.2, 1.8)], 'crt': [('l', 2.3, 4.1), ('ml', 2100, 3400)]}

#will be applied for each row in the dataframe
def fill_unit(row):
    test = row['URINE_TEST'] #get test
    value = row['VALUES']   #get value
    unit = row['UNIT']     #get initial unit

    if test in test_dic.keys():
        if test_dic[test][0][1] <= value <=test_dic[test][0][2]:
            unit = test_dic[test][0][0]
        elif test_dic[test][1][1] <= value <=test_dic[test][1][2]:
            unit = test_dic[test][1][0]

        else:
            unit = np.nan

    return unit

urine_data['UNIT'] = urine_data.apply(fill_unit, axis=1)
```

which will give you as output:

```
URINE_TEST  UNIT    VALUES
0   alb mg  1500.0
1   alb mg  1200.0
2   alb mg  1600.0
3   alb g   1.2
4   alb g   1.8
5   alb mg  1300.0
6   crt l   2.3
7   crt l   3.3
8   crt l   4.1
9   crt ml  2500.0
10  crt ml  3400.0
11  crt ml  2100.0
12  crt l   3.0
13  crt NaN 99.0
```

Comment: possible, but you have to generate a dictionary manually everything you get a new dataframe? I think the OP is asking how to get it from within the data frame

Comment: Yes, the above is just a vanilla example. Answer should not be hardcoded.

Comment: Also, avoid using apply as it can be vey slow. It is best to make use of vectorized functions for most problems.